# Как эффективно описать кнопки калькулятора?

Tags: c++, qt

Решил написать калькулятор и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: 
дабы не громоздить лишний код, создаю один слот `digitClicked()`, для обработки сигналов цифр.

Решил воспользоваться для этого `QSignalMapper`, но как потом понял, он больше применим для динамически создаваемых объектов, а у меня кнопки уже отрисованы.
В итоге все равно получилось много кода. Можно ли как-то по другому описать кнопки? Или подредактировать мой код.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    operandClicked = true;
    QSignalMapper *mapperDigit = new QSignalMapper(this);

    /* digits */
    mapperDigit->setMapping( ui->Button0, "0" );
    mapperDigit->setMapping( ui->Button1, "1" );
    mapperDigit->setMapping( ui->Button2, "2" );
    mapperDigit->setMapping( ui->Button3, "3" );
    mapperDigit->setMapping( ui->Button4, "4" );
    mapperDigit->setMapping( ui->Button5, "5" );
    mapperDigit->setMapping( ui->Button6, "6" );
    mapperDigit->setMapping( ui->Button7, "7" );
    mapperDigit->setMapping( ui->Button8, "8" );
    mapperDigit->setMapping( ui->Button9, "9" );

    connect( ui->Button0, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );
    connect( ui->Button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );
    connect( ui->Button2, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );
    connect( ui->Button3, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );
    connect( ui->Button4, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );
    connect( ui->Button5, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );
    connect( ui->Button6, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );
    connect( ui->Button7, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );
    connect( ui->Button8, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );
    connect( ui->Button9, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );

    connect( mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this, SLOT(digetClicked(QString)) );
}

void MainWindow::digetClicked(const QString &s)
{
    if (ui->display->text() == "0" && s == "0") {
        return;
}

if (operandClicked) {
    ui->display->clear();
    operandClicked = false;
}

    ui->display->setText(ui->display->text() + s);
}
```

Comment: Приветствую. Если для себя, то можно и по-другому описать. Используя не qt, а MVC формы.

Comment: не для себя, нужен именно qt

Comment: Банальная оптимизация - сделать временный массив указателей на кнопки, заполнить его (вручную, всеми 10 кнопками), а потом в цикле сделать setMapping() и connect(). В Qt'шном дизайнере сразу сделать массив кнопок я тоже не умею...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно запросить дочерние виджеты по именам:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    QPushButton* btn=findChild<QPushButton*>( QString("Button%1").arg(i) );
    mapperDigit->setMapping( btn, QString("%1").arg(i) );
    connect( btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать обычный сигнал, наподобие такого:

```
void MainWindow::digetClicked()
{
     QString ch = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(QObject::sender())->text();
     //обработка
}
```